# Is there a slowest creature in D&D, if so which?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, movement

Based off of my other question [What creature or vehicle has the fastest unmodified speed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171415/64735), I'm wondering if there is a possibly a slowest creature in D&D 3.5e?

I am looking for basic speed, no modifications of any kind: magic, psionics, levels, templates, feats, whatever. Just unmodified as-it-is-printed. Something that I can point to.

Unlike my other question, just creatures, not vehicles.

Comment: Isn't this just going to be a list of 0 speed creatures?

Answer (score 8):

Note: There are bound to be ties. I have picked one creature from each speed category.

The [Shrieker](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/3e_SRD:Fungus,_Shrieker) is an example of a creature with a move speed of zero.

If you are looking for non-zero move speeds, the [toad](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/3e_SRD:Toad) has a 5 ft. move speed.

If you are looking for non-zero move speeds where the creature is large enough to be ridden, it is still 5 ft. One example is the Giant Termite Queen from Sandstorm, page 198.

Comment: Why would the one creature you give an example of be important? Is there a reason you've chosen it to be the answer to the question?

Comment: @NautArch The question is asking for something to point to. These are examples that are easy to point to. So, the SRD is my first choice (as it can be linked or found in the Monster Manual I). Next, I would assume splatbooks published by WotC would be fairly common fare. Finally, I would look to dragon magazine and third party sources. Since I found examples in the SRD, they seem the most relevant. I did not find any examples of 5 ft. move speed creatures in the SRD that are large enough to be ridden.

Comment: I don't see the requirement that it be used as a mount? where is that coming from?

Comment: The reference to the other post included vehicles, implying the creature or vehicle may be used as a mode of transportation (unclear). For this question, vehicles are not included, but if the OP is still looking for the slowest potential mode of transportation (where the creature is actually capable of movement), the giant termite queen might be a logical choice.

Comment: The **[formian](http://dndsrd.net/monstersEtoF.html#formian) queen** has a speed of 0 ft., too, if another example is needed.